# Question about open sets as described in Sierpinski's General Topology.

Tags: general-topology

When introducing topological spaces, Sierpinski states:

"If $p\in K$, $q\in K$, and $p\neq q$, there exists an set $U \in \phi$ such that $p \in U$ and $q \notin U$."[p.39]

Here $K$ is a topological space and $\phi$ is the family of all open sets.

As far as I can see, this property contradicts that the indiscrete topology on a set with at least 2 elements forms a topological space. What am I missing here?

Comment: If he says so, Sierpinski excludes topological spaces which are not [T1-separated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space). Hence you are right, this excludes the indiscrete topology on a set with at least 2 elements.

Comment: I doubt he wrote "an set". Anyway, context matters. Are you sure he wasn't talking about a specific open set or a specific type of topology?

Comment: This "an" is the only difference with the text. In chapter 1, Sierpiński allows any topology and gives the discrete and indiscrete ones as examples (p. 3). In chapter 2, he restricts to T1-spaces.